# Getting time difference of two consecutive rows in SQL

Tags: sql

I use the following Query to get the results as shown below:

```
SELECT
    calls.[Activity ID_18],
    calls.[Call SMS],
    calls.[Created By] PA_Name,
    calls.LOB,
    calls.Date,
    calls.StartDate Time_of_Call,
    calls.[Duration (min)] Duration,
    calls.[Call Connected?] 'Connected?'
FROM
    [dbo].[tblcallsnew] calls
WHERE
    CAST(calls.Date AS date) >= '3/15/2020' AND calls.LOB IN ('SO','EM')
ORDER BY
    PA_Name,CAST(calls.StartDate AS datetime2)
```

I get the following Result with the query above:

```
Activity ID_18    Call SMS  PA_Name         LOB Date       Time_of_Call    Duration Connected?
00T2s000003U4uIEAS  Call    Aaron Fernandes EM  2020-03-16  2020-03-16 15:59:00 0.68    0
00T2s000003U4oMEAS  Call    Aaron Fernandes EM  2020-03-16  2020-03-16 16:02:00 0.07    0
00T2s000003U4z7EAC  Call    Aaron Fernandes EM  2020-03-16  2020-03-16 16:03:00 0.43    0
00T2s000003U59EEAS  Call    Aaron Fernandes EM  2020-03-16  2020-03-16 16:08:00 0.45    0
00T2s000003U517EAC  Call    Aaron Fernandes EM  2020-03-16  2020-03-16 16:10:00 3.37    1
00T2s000003U5MJEA0  Call    Aaron Fernandes EM  2020-03-16  2020-03-16 16:17:00 0.50    0
00T2s000003U5ApEAK  Call    Aaron Fernandes EM  2020-03-16  2020-03-16 16:18:00 0.08    0
```

What I want is: I want to get the time elapsed between two consecutive calls by each PA NAME (agent). 
The Idea is to get how much time an agent spends between two calls.

Any help on this will be appreciated.

Comment: Tag your question with the database you are using.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `lead()`:

```
select c.*,
       lead(startDate) over (partition by pa_name order by startDate) as next_startDate,
       datediff(minute, startDate,
                lead(startDate) over (partition by pa_name order by startDate)
               ) as minutes_between        
from [dbo].[tblcallsnew] c
where c.Date  >= '2020-03-15' and c.LOB in ('SO','EM')
```